# When does table view gets created?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, tableview

I have trouble in understanding when does table 
View gets created.

I have two tab view. In second tab view I have table whose `datasource` is been
Adhered to the table view protocol.

Whenever the second tab is selected /clicked the tables datasource method
`numberOfRowsInTableView` is called on every click.

I'm using xcode 4.2.

Is that because each tab view recreates its view when the tab selected?

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

> I have trouble in understanding when does table View gets created.

If it's in a nib, it's created when you load the nib.

Actually, it depends on what you mean by “created”. You created it when you put the table view into the nib in Xcode. When you save, Xcode archives that object into the nib.

Then, at run time, when your app loads the nib, Cocoa unarchives the table view (along with everything else in the nib). That unarchiving is the moment of “creation” after which the table view exists in your app.

> Whenever the second tab is selected /clicked the tables datasource method `numberOfRowsInTableView` is called on every click.

The table view already exists by then. It sends that message (among other data source messages) whenever it becomes visible, whether or not it's becoming visible for the first time.

If you switch to a different tab, the table view has no reason to show anything, so it won't bother following updates to the model.

If you then switch back, making the table view visible, now the table view has a reason to show something, so it needs to know if anything has changed so it can show the model's current state. So, it rechecks its data source at that time.

Answer (score -1):

It depends if the content of TableView is dynamic or static. If it's dynamic it's created when the method `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`called. If the content is static it's created when loading the view. Note that `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called more than one time, it gets called as the count of the datasource items. Hope that helps :)

Comment: No, the table view is created before it calls `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. (Table views that don't exist yet can't send messages.) Moreover, that method doesn't exist in Cocoa.

Comment: I know but I don't think it'd be useful if there was one, what matters to the developer is when the content is being created